# May gentile "half-twins" marry?

Tags: halacha, gentiles, pregnancy-birth, arayot, twins

If a pregnant divorced gentile woman marries a different man and then conceives another child of opposite gender through [superfetation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfetation#In_humans), are the twins considered only half-siblings and permitted to marry?

Comment: "half-siblings and permitted to marry" Can you source that? My (admittedly imperfect) memory is that the halfness has to go the other way.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about gentiles marrying - not Jews. Please edit and clarify.

Comment: @DanF Jews marrying would not be on topic...

Comment: @Nbz On the subject. A posek I was once studying under told me about a woman he knew who had both ovaries cycling at the same time. This is exactly the situation needed for superfetation. He said she had an extremely hard time getting clean as far as nidda goes. But he also said it was only temporary, after her next pregnancy her body straightened out and went back to each ovary taking turns with the other.

Comment: @DanF Judaism has halachos for non-Jews as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yichus for nonjews according to Jewish law follows the mother. See [Rambam hilchos milachim umilchamos chapter 9 halacha 5](http://mechon-mamre.org/i/e509.htm#7). Therefore these children are complete siblings as far as we are concerned.

I would like to add for the sake of clarity however that even relationships that are allowed such as a father marrying a daughter are off limits due to the fact that the non-Jews already decided to distance themselves from forbidden arayos. This is what the gemara meant by saying Lot's intentions were for an aveira, see [tosafos in maseches Nazir 23a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=17&daf=23&format=pdf).